# Third order ODE initial value problem,solution obeys $y(x) \rightarrow 0 $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ ???

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''' + y'' -y' -y=0$
$y(0)=7,y'(0)=-3,y''(0)=\alpha$

Find all values of $\alpha$ for which the solution obeys $y(x) \rightarrow 0 $ as $x 
\rightarrow \infty$

Here is my work

I used the cubic characteristic equation $r^3 +r^2 -r -1 = 0$ and find the three roots to be
$-1,-1$and $1$

So my general solution is $y(x) = Ae^x+Be^{-x}+Cxe^{-x}$

and

$y'(x) = Ae^x-Be^{-x}+Ce^{-x}-Cxe^{-x}$

$y''(x) = Ae^x+Be^{-x}+-2Ce^{-x}+Cxe^{-x}$

Use the given initial values, I get

$y(0) = 7 = A+B$

$y'(0) = -3 = A-B+C$

$y''(0)=\alpha = A+B-2C$

What should I do next to determine all the values of $\alpha$ such that the solution obeys $y(x) \rightarrow 0 $ as $x 
\rightarrow \infty$ ???

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: $A$ needs to be zero, so just solve your system for $A$ and find a value of $\alpha$ that makes it zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \to \infty$, $e^x \to \infty$, so we must set $A = 0$ in order to guarantee that $y(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Then from $y(0) = 7 = A + B$, we see that $A = 0$ implies that $B = 7$.

From $y'(0) = -3 = A - B + C$, we get $-3 = -B + C = -7 + C$, so $C = 4$.

From $y''(0) = \alpha = B - 2C$, we get $\alpha = 7 - 8 = -1$. Then $\alpha = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875528/solving-an-ordinary-differential-equation-with-initial-conditions/875746#875746). Note that, you are asked that your solution satisfies certain condition which is $\lim_{x\to \infty} y(x) = 0 $, so this makes you to consider only the solutions $y_1=e^{-x}$ and $y_2=xe^{-x}$ which gives

> $$ y(x) = Ae^{-x} + Bxe^{-x}. $$

Now, you should determine the constants $A$ and $B$ using the initial conditions.